# Hugging Face Deep RL Course: Huggy Environment on M1 Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine, apple-m1, reinforcement-learning, huggingface

I am starting the Hugging Face Deep Reinforcement Learning Course. I am following this [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/learn/deep-rl-course/unitbonus1/train) locally on my M1 Mac instead of in Google Colab. I am able to do all of the steps until the training step:

> mlagents-learn ./config/ppo/Huggy.yaml --env=./trained-envs-executables/linux/Huggy/Huggy --run-id="Huggy" --no-graphics

I get the following error:

> mlagents_envs.exception.UnityEnvironmentException: Couldn't launch the ./trained-envs-executables/linux/Huggy/Huggy environment. Provided filename does not match any environments.

In my trained-envs-executables/linux/Huggy folder, I have a Huggy.x86_64 file. I tried setting the env to that and just the Huggy folder (not Huggy twice) but neither worked.

I downloaded the env from [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zv3M95ZJTWHUVOWT6ckq_cm98nft8gdF). Is this the correct environment to use or am I calling the environment incorrectly? I also tried running from the Rosetta terminal but no luck.